# How can I use new Function in map clause

Tags: rxjs

I want to convert string to code.
I know eval() is not good due to security issue.
I am trying to assign dynamic code in map clause in the following code.
How can I use new Function to achieve this please?

```
let code = 'x => x.myCheckbox'; 
this.myForm.valueChanges
.pipe(
  map(eval(code))
)
.subscribe(y => console.log(y))
```

Comment: `map( x => x.myCheckbox)`